# Parse HTML from local file

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, lxml

I'm using Google App Engine with Python. I want to get the tree of a HTML file from the same project as my Python script. I tried many things, like using the absolute url (e.g http://localhost:8080/nl/home.html) and the relative url (/nl/home.html). Both don't seem to work. I use this code:

```
class HomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):    
    def get(self):

        path = self.request.path

        htmlfile = etree.parse(path)
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('/nl/template.html')

        pagetitle = htmlfile.find(".//title").text
        body = htmlfile.get_element_by_id("body").toString()
```

It returns the following error:
IOError: Error reading file '/nl/home.html': failed to load external entity "/nl/home.html

Does anyone know how to get the tree of a HTML file from the same project with Python?

**EDIT**

This is the working code:

```
class HomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):    
def get(self):

    path = self.request.path.replace("/","",1)
    logging.info(path)

    htmlfile = html.fromstring(urllib.urlopen(path).read())   
    template = jinja_environment.get_template('/nl/template.html')

    pagetitle = htmlfile.find(".//title").text
    body = innerHTML(htmlfile.get_element_by_id("body"))

def innerHTML(node): 
    buildString = ''
    for child in node:
        buildString += html.tostring(child)
    return buildString
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your working directory is the base of your app directory. So if your app is organized like:

- app.yaml
- nl/

  - home.html

You can then read your file at `nl/html.html` (assuming you haven't changed your working directory).

Comment: Is that documented somewhere? That the working directory is the base of the app directory? I could not find anything specific about it, so I used the mechanism described in my answer to get the path of my app files...

Comment: I can't find formal documentation but it's mentioned as a Tip on the [Using Templates](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates) page.

Comment: Ok, that is as good a documentation as I have grown to expect from Google (no offense, but seriously, how is the documentation this bad..).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot! Eventually, some more edits to my code had to be made, see my question for the working code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a permissions issue; check that you're python script can access the file. Does it work if you make that file available to everyone?

Comment: I added the following code to my app.yaml file:
- url: /nl
  static_dir: nl
  application_readable: true
But it is still not working unfortunatelly

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is in the path to your file. You are assuming that your app directory is root of the filesystem on the server. This does not have to be the case. Actually, I could not find any documentation on where the files will be, so this is what I do (it works on the dev server, I have not tired it in production yet):

I assume that Google preserves the relative locations of the files in my application. So if I know the location of one file, I can determine the location of the rest of my files. Luckily the python specification allows you to programmatically determine the location of a python source file like so:

```
def get_src_dir(){
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
}
```

get_src_dir() you will get the location of the source file.

```
os.path.join(get_src_dir(), rel_path_to_asset)
```

will now get you the path to your asset. rel_path_to_asset is path to asset relative to the source file the get_src_dir() function is in...